# Set entire page's css on click?

Tags: javascript, css, click, set, document

Does anyone know how I can change the entire document's CSS file on click? I've searched around but only found a few results on setting a class/ID's CSS, not the entire document. My website has two themes, light/dark, and I want to load up "light.css" or "dark.css" from two links.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the src of the the link tag, which controls the styles. For example, you probably have this in your head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="light.css">
```

You need to change the href attribute of the link tag to "dark.css" when you click something. You can do that like this:

```
document.getElementById('id-of-element').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].setAttribute('href',isDark?'light.css':'dark.css');
    isDark=isDark?false:true;
}
```

IMPORTANT: you need to set isDark to false or true before this code, depending on whether the page is supposed to be dark or light in the beginning. You also need to change `id-of-element` to the id of the element that should be clicked to toggle the state of the page.

I think this is better than the other answers because it is simpler and uses no jquery.

EDIT: I accidentally had the src attribute instead of the href one before. I now updated it to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can do using theming. But the changing of CSS is limited to the `<body>` tag.

```
$("a.theme").click(function(){
    $("body").addClass("dark");
});
```

I have used [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library to make the coding easier. And it is not a good idea to switch CSS rather, you can change the classes.

#### Demo

You can check out the working demo in [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/21192).

Check out this answer for more details: [Selecting a web page look and feel without reloading, with one CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15185652/462627).

Comment: That involves rewriting my entire website and css file... all I need is a css FILE switcher

Comment: @Windbrand What browsers do you support? Some versions of all the browsers actually deny this because of security issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="light">Light</a>
<a href="#" id="dark">Dark</a>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('a#light, a#dark').click(function(){
        $('style').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://www.example.com/' + $this.attr('id') + '.css',
            success:function(data){
                $('<style></style>').appendTo('head').html(data);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Of course, you need to load jQuery first.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways that come immediately to mind.

1) Add a style tag to the page's head, ensuring that the style tag has a unique id. You can then set the innerHTML of that element. (somewhat messy)

2) Add a link tag to the page's head, also ensuring that it has a unique id. You set the type='text/css' and the rel='stylesheet' attributes. You the set the src of this link element to the appropriate css file.

Here's an example of each type. Just supply css files for theme3() and theme4() functions.

**Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function toggleClass(element, newStr)
{
    index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
    else
    {
        if (index != 0)
            newStr = ' '+newStr;
        element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
    }
}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    var style = newEl('style');
    style.setAttribute('id', 'dynCss');
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    var style2 = newEl('link');
    style2.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    style2.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    style2.setAttribute('id', 'dynCss2');
    document.head.appendChild(style2);
}

function theme1()
{
    var style = byId('dynCss');
    style.innerHTML = "h1{color: red;}";

    var style2 = byId('dynCss2');
    style2.setAttribute('href', '');
}

function theme2()
{
    var style = byId('dynCss');
    style.innerHTML = "h1{color: blue;}";

    var style2 = byId('dynCss2');
    style2.setAttribute('href', '');
}

function theme3()
{
    var style = byId('dynCss');
    style.innerHTML = "";

    var style2 = byId('dynCss2');
    style2.setAttribute('href', 'style3.css');
}

function theme4()
{
    var style = byId('dynCss');
    style.innerHTML = "";
    var style2 = byId('dynCss2');
    style2.setAttribute('href', 'style4.css');
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the heading</h1>
    <input type='button' onclick='theme1();' value='Theme 1'/>
    <input type='button' onclick='theme2();' value='Theme 2'/>

    <input type='button' onclick='theme3();' value='Theme 3'/>
    <input type='button' onclick='theme4();' value='Theme 4'/>
</body>
</html>
```